# C++ single quotes in the middle of a number

Tags: c++, c++14

source [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). The question is that I don't understand what is going in the for loop here.

```
for(long n = 0; n != 1'000'000; ++n) l.push(n);
```

Is `n != 1'000'000` equivalent to `n != 1000000`?

Comment: Since C++14, single-quotes can be used to specify commas in a number. So, the answer to your question is yes.